# Is there any way to whitelist spacy labelling?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm new to spaCy and currently trying to use spaCy english large model to identify PERSON from sentences 
All is fine to identify PERSON from sentences until I found some name that's identified is not PERSON. 
E.g. If I put "Alex is eating apple". It will successfully return Alex is a PERSON 
But when this case happens, it won't work anymore
E.g. Sun Saw Bee is eating apple **or** Alexandro Soon is eating apple

I'm wondering if there is anything like whitelist to add in "Sun Saw Bee" or "Alexandro Soon" as a PERSON without retraining spaCy english model? 
or any way to somehow identify "Sun Saw Bee" as a PERSON instead?
if there is any link related to this perhaps can share as well, since my keyword searching might not hitting the right key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of known entities, you can use an [`EntityRuler`](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) in combination with the NER model. Depending on your task/priorities, you may want to add it before or after the NER model in the pipeline.

Here is a simple example (adapted from the docs linked above) that shows how you can use either phrase patterns (strings) or token-based matcher patterns to define the entities to match:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Apple"},
            {"label": "GPE", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "san"}, {"LOWER": "francisco"}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler, before="ner")

doc = nlp("Apple is opening its first big office in San Francisco after opening an office in New York City.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

Output with spacy v2.3.2:

```
[('Apple', 'ORG'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE'), ('New York City', 'GPE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

One would not want to whitelist a name in the Spacy pipeline. Spacy is created for NER detection based on decisions created by the model, not by the end-user. One of the limitations of the currently available models, as noted on their website, is that many of them are trained on wikipedia and other sources, which may not reflect your target data.

Whitelisting an entity is the same as searching;

```
if "Sun Saw Bee" in text:
    print('person')
```

[What you can do is add data to a model, which basically  is retraining the model.](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-ner)